# agent cannot connect to itself error when trying to connected to a random agent on startup in anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I have a population of agents in an environment and I am trying to create a network of agents to represent family by connecting to other agents with the same origin. family is a collection of bidirectional links in the agent person.

I have used the code on startup

```
for(int i =0; i<5000; i++){
population.get(i).family.connectTo(randomFrom(population));
}
```

When this is run i get the error message

```
Error during model startup
root.population[4005]:
Cannot connect an agent to itself
```

How can I remove this error?

Answer (score 0):

You just search for other agents until this other agent is not you:

```
for(int i =0; i<5000; i++){
    Agent randomOtherAgent = randomFrom(population);
    while (randomOtherAgent.equals(population.get(i)) { 
        randomOtherAgent = randomFrom(population); // try to find someone else
    }
    // now you found someone not equal to yourself
    population.get(i).family.connectTo(randomOtherAgent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked once I changed the 3rd line to while (randomOtherAgent.equals(population.get(i)) {

Comment: great. Please mark this as "helpful" (up arrow next to my answer) to help others find this in the future as well. I will amend my answer (didn't test the code ;-) )